# Node js ошибка с Promise

Tags: node.js, promise

Мой код ругается, не видит переменную после добавления Promise. Что я не так делаю? 
`(node:11696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'pass' of undefined
(node:11696) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

```js
function onSignin(post_obj) {
  if ((post_obj.email.length > 0) && (post_obj.pass.length > 0))
    {
      db_check_user_1_log_2_pass(post_obj.email, post_obj.pass).then( new Promise(function (arg) {
          assert.equal(arg[0].pass, post_obj.pass);
          return true
      }) )

    }
  else {
    console.log('invalid post');
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Кто вас учил так промизы создавать?

Comment: Никто, вот разбираюсь

Comment: Прочтите внимательнее примеры кода по ссылке которую вам давали